# Problem installing Dolphin emulator

Tags: 14.04, emulation

I have tried to install dolphin emulator using ppa.

I added the ppa, updated then I tried to install using `sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu`. It said that the package was not found.

I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Which PPA are you using?

Comment: ppa:glennric/dolphin-emu

Answer (score 2):

I just received the same error, while trying to reproduce the error you experienced.

You need to do `sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu-master` by the look of my error. It allowed me to start to install (i.e. it found the package), although I did cancel it.

Was this what you got?

```
tim@Hairy14:~$ sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package dolphin-emu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  dolphin-emu-master

E: Package 'dolphin-emu' has no installation candidate
```

NB: I used [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-dolphin-emulator-ubuntu-ppa-repository/) site to get the PPA details, the same PPA as you.

Comment: The PPA's launchpad site is [here](https://launchpad.net/~glennric/+archive/dolphin-emu) - you can also download the deb file from the Dolphin Emulator site [here](https://dolphin-emu.org/download/?ref=btn#download-stable), and you can then install that.

Comment: I used apt-get install dolphin-emu-master but its not working<br>rohan@rohan-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu[sudo] password for rohan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dolphin-emu
rohan@rohan-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu-master
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dolphin-emu-master

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Dolphins website](https://dolphin-emu.org/download/) - at this time their downloads only support up to Ubuntu 13.10.  There are some alternate PPAs that apparently support Ubuntu 14.04, and a google search will find those for you.

Comment: It worked for me though.

Comment: I searched and I couldnt find any

Comment: I googled "dolphin emulator ubuntu 14.04" and got several hits.  The one I would put most credence in is on launchpad, who indicate that the PPA source is "untrusted"

Answer (score 0):

I thought that is because dolphin-emu doesnt support 32 bit anymore. so if you are using ubuntu trusty 32 bit, you cant download the packages via ppa because the 32 bit version is not being developed anymore so no exist either for future ubuntu 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 17.04**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu-master
dolphin-emu
```

The PPA with the `-master` packaged is needed in 17.04 to overcome this bug: https://bugs.dolphin-emu.org/issues/9853